# How to use textview in Android's PreferenceScreen?

Tags: java, android

I would like to use textview in PreferenceScreen, it's a longer text that explains some specific setting. If I use summary or title attribute on some versions it gets formatted weirdly, doesn't display correctly etc. (The text is rather long).

Therefor I find it would be the best to use textview, is it possible to create custom settings element?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can assign layout resource for your preference in your xml file, using tag `android:layout="@layout/your_pref_layout"`.

Don't forget to use proper ids in your layout (android:id="@+android:id/title", android:id="@+android:id/summary") to assign views to be used as title/summary views.

For more info see for example this: [Creating a custom layout for preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194116/creating-a-custom-layout-for-preferences)

or this: [How to add a button to PreferenceScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697233/how-to-add-a-button-to-preferencescreen)

Comment: Yes, thank you, I did that. Now I have problem that I don't know how to assing proper height for my new element... wrap_content, fill_parent etc not working, most of the text is missing, since its long paragraph.

Comment: I would try wrap_content..did you also assign the textview to be multiline (by defining maxLines/singleLine=false)?

Answer (score 29):

Use this:

```
<Preference
        android:selectable="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:key="example_key"
        android:title="example_title"
        android:summary="anything_you_want" />
```

The attributes **selectable** will decide the click action of the Preference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can create a layout and use that layout file to inflate as your preference screen you can see a example here.

[custom EditTextPreference: can't get TextView by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455109/custom-edittextpreference-cant-get-textview-by-id)